# Question about setting btime - would this question I posted over on the Unix stack be better here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364976/how-to-change-bsds-file-birth-time-aka-btime

I posted a Q about how to set btime (BSD's file Birth time) on files. I'm wondering if the community here thinkgs this might be a better fit here. No one has close voted over on Unix, but I don't want to just cross post it here :)

Comment: I've seen https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49154/how-to-change-the-creation-st-birthtime-date-time-of-a-file-in-lion but I'm not sure it exactly answers my actual Q

Comment: ...wait, actually, in that Q I found another linked Q, and I'm off looking at SetFile (part of apple dev kit, which I have).  brb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking, and for avoiding a cross-post.

Generally the question seems to be on-topic on both sites (at least as long as you are looking for end user solutions and don't want to develop your own piece of code). So if you don't get an answer on the Unix site, please flag it and have a moderator over there migrate it to AD.

PS: And yes, seems like you've already found the two questions relating to the topic :-)

Comment: yeup, SetFile from the apple developer tools solves my problem. I'll answe rmy own Q over on Unix and leave breadcrumbs to the two Qs here on AD. Thanks!